# Camera follow player around planet

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a planet and a player moving on it using gravity. I would like to have a camera to follow the player around it. Using the Parent Constraint component works perfectly, but I want to delay the rotation follow, so I have to use a script. I just cannot figure out how to make it follow it around the globe. I either have a camera that completely freaks out, or a camera that sort of follows the player but doesn't move over the planet and always stays in front of it. And often the position following works, but as soon as I add something that changes rotation it only does that. I've tried many different scripts but nothing works. I'm grateful for any help.

EDIT
I'm sorry for not adding an example. At the moment I've tried this script attached to the camera:

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;        
    private Vector3 offset;  

void Start()
    {       
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, player.transform.rotation, 50f * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
```

The camera does mimic the rotation of the player, but the position isn't being follow correctly anymore. It seems mostly stuck in place, moving only very slightly.

Comment: For something like that, I would recommend using Cinemachine. There is plenty of yt tutorials on it

Comment: Merely saying "nothing works" is too vague to be useful to people trying to answer your question.  It would improve the question greatly if you included one example of a script that you tried and explained how that script behaved and how that behavior is different from what you expected.

Comment: Fair dinkums, but I honestly tried so many things I didn't know what to add in the end. I apologise!

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a camera following a GameObject, you need to go to the camera you want following the GameObject, select **Add component**, write FollowPlayer, press **New script**, and then press **select and add**. Edit the script so it contains the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = player.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Then, you will need to drag and drop the GameObject you want the camera to follow, in the "Player" box.
Define the offset of the camera from the GameObject, and your'e good to go.

Comment: Oh, didn't get that the first time I read your'e question. I believe this might help: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-do-you-make-an-object-follow-your-exact-movement-but-delayed.512787/